# Google BigQuery - Error while downloading data to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to work with the github data which has been uploaded to Google's big data. I ran a few queries (which generated a lot of rows -

eg: a query `SELECT  actor_attributes_login, repository_watchers , repository_forks  FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
where repository_watchers > 2 and REGEXP_MATCH(repository_created_at, '2012-')
ORDER BY actor_attributes_login;`

The answer had more than 2,20,000 rows. When I attempted to download to CSV , it said

> Download Unavailable
>   This result set contains too many rows for direct download. Please use "Save as Table" and then export the resulting table.

When I tried to do it as Save as Table I got the following error:

> Access Denied: Job publicdata:job_c2338ba91e494b21970854e13cdc4b2a: RUN_JOB

Also, I ran queries where I limited the number of rows to 200 or so, even in such cases I got the error as mentioned above. However I was able to download it as CSV.

Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Anerudh You don't have access to modify the *publicdata* samples dataset. Create a brand new dataset, and try to save your query results to a new table in that dataset.